# Using "Either" in data validation

Tags: haskell

I have a program which is dedicated to create "Student" (First Name, Last Name, Age) and validate input data. My problem is that: when I insert student which e.g either name hasn't 2 letters or age is lower than 18 - the program only show one error. How to use "Either function" to create for example a string which contains all errors ?

```
module Student where

data Student = Student {firstName::FirstName, lastName::LastName, age::Age}
  deriving Show

newtype FirstName = FirstName String
  deriving Show

newtype LastName = LastName String
  deriving Show

newtype Age = Age Int
  deriving Show

mkStudent :: String -> String -> String -> Either String Student
mkStudent fn ln a = 
   Student <$> validate fn
           <*> validate ln
           <*> validate a

aceptableLetters = ['a'..'z']++['A'..'Z']

validateFn :: String -> Either String FirstName
validateFn fn 
   | length fn < 2 = Left "First name has to at least 2 letters"
   | length fn > 100 = Left "First name is limited to 100 characters"
   | not . null $ filter (\c -> not . elem c $ aceptableLetters) fn = Left "First name contains unacceptable chars"
   | otherwise = Right . FirstName $ fn

validateLn :: String -> Either String LastName
validateLn lastName 
   | length lastName < 2 = Left "Last name has to at least 2 letters"
   | length lastName > 100 = Left "Last name is limited to 100 characters"
   | not . null $ filter (\c -> not . elem c $ aceptableLetters) lastName = Left "Last name contains unacceptable chars"
   | otherwise = Right . LastName $ lastName

validateA :: String -> Either String Age
validateA a
   | age <= 18 = Left "Student has to be at least 18"
   | age > 100 = Left "Student has more than 100 years. Probably it is an error."
   | otherwise = Right . Age $ age
   where
    age = read a

class Validate v where
    validate :: String -> Either String v

instance Validate FirstName where
    validate=validateFn

instance Validate LastName where
    validate=validateLn

instance Validate Age where
    validate=validateA
```

Answer (score 11):

Either's Monad and Applicative instances *can't* accumulate errors. Any implementation that did so would be in violation of the monad laws. They must stop at the first Left value. So if you want to use Either to accumulate errors, you have to do it by hand, not through the Applicative or Monad instances.

What you're looking for instead is [Validation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-5.0.1.1/docs/Data-Either-Validation.html). With that, you could write:

```
causes :: Applicative f => Bool -> a -> Validation (f a) ()
True `causes` err = Failure $ pure err
False `causes` err = Success ()

validateA :: String -> Validation [String] Age
validateA a = (Success . Age $ age)
           <* (age <= 18) `causes` "Student has to be at least 18"
           <* (age > 100) `causes` "Student has more than 100 years. Probably it is an error."
  where age = read a
```

and similarly for your other validators. `mkStudent` remains as you have written it: applicative combinators are the right way to combine Validation values.

Answer (score 0):

A basic way would be to define a custom helper function which collects the errors in a list:

```
collectError :: Error e a -> [e]
collectError (Left e) = [e]
collectError _        = []   -- no errors
```

Then, we can exploit the helper as follows:

```
mkStudent :: String -> String -> String -> Either [String] Student
mkStudent fn ln a = case (validate fn, validate ln, validate a) of
   (Right xfn, Right xln, Right xa) -> Right (Student xfn xln xa)
   (efn      , eln      , ea      ) ->
      Left (collectError efn ++ collectError eln ++ collectError ea)
```

This is probably not the most elegant way, but it is simple.

---

If this pattern is frequently used in a program, I'd be tempted to craft a custom `Applicative` which logs all the errors. Something like

```
data Result e a = Error e | OK a 
  deriving Functor

instance Semigroup e => Applicative (Result e) where
   pure = OK
   (OK f) <*> (OK x) = OK $ f x
   (Error e1) <*> (Error e2) = Error (e1 <> e2)
   (Error e1) <*> _          = Error e1
   _          <*> (Error e2) = Error e2
```

(This should already exist in the libraries under some name.)

Then,

```
mkStudent :: String -> String -> String -> Result [String] Student
mkStudent fn ln a = 
   Student <$> validate fn
           <*> validate ln
           <*> validate a
```

should just work, provided the validation function return `Error ["message"]` on failure, with return type `Result [String] T`.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be to change the left `Either` to a custom data type. What I mean is that, instead of having `Either String Age`, you could have `Either ErrorType Age`, and then define

```
data ErrorType = LowAge | WrongName
```

In my opinion this would also be better programming practice because you'd be separating the error throwing and its handler. Especially in Haskell and functional programming, I wouldn't carry around string representations to handle errors. Then you can for example combine the errors into a list, i.e:

```
mkStudent :: String -> String -> String -> Either [ErrorType] Student
```

Then just have another function to handle the list and print it to the user, or log it, or anything you'd want to do with it.